# nginx-proxy always returning 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm following the [example docker compose](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy) for an nginx-proxy, but it always returns a `301 Moved Permanently` error. I'm using docker hosted in Ubuntu 22.04.

my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: nginxproxy/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ../certificates:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
    depends_on:
      - whoami

  whoami:
    image: jwilder/whoami
    expose:
      - "8000"
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=whoami.media.local
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8000
```

my test command and output:

```
user@media:~/docker/nginx-test$ curl -H "Host: whoami.media.local" media.local
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.25.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

output from the nginx log

```
nginx-proxy_1  | nginx.1     | whoami.media.local 192.168.0.2 - - [11/Aug/2023:16:57:07 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 169 "-" "curl/7.81.0" "-"
```

I've tried adding `192.168.0.2 whoami.media.local` to my host's `/etc/hosts` file and the result is the same:

```
user@media:~/docker/nginx-test$ curl -I whoami.media.local
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.25.1
Date: Fri, 11 Aug 2023 17:00:57 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 169
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://whoami.media.local/
```

per the website example, the expected output is: `I'm 5b129ab83266`

What am I getting wrong in my system configuration?

Comment: You've taken the working example and associated test command, made modifications to the docker-compose but kept the test command.

Have you tried the basic example without editing anything and then started editing to see where you went wrong?

Your `curl -I` looks pretty clear to me.

Comment: my only change of consequence was to update the VIRTUAL_HOST parameter to match my system. I can remove the port 443, certificate directory, and dependency and the result is the same.

Comment: Surprising given the block in which the redirection to https occurs in the [nginx configuration template](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy/blob/main/nginx.tmpl#L541).

Comment: Are you saying that even without exposing certificates the `cert_ok` condition is true?

Comment: that's a compelling point... I'll re-verify my assumptions.

Comment: you were correct. it was the cert modifications I made combined with bad assumptions. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your issue is that `nginx-proxy` is redirecting to HTTPS, but you haven't set up SSL for `whoami.media.local`.

**Possible Solutions**:

1. **Add SSL**: Ensure SSL certificates for `whoami.media.local` are in the `../certificates` directory.
2. **Disable HTTPS Redirect**: Add `HTTPS_METHOD=noredirect` to the `nginx-proxy` environment in your `docker-compose.yml`.

```
yaml
nginx-proxy:
  ...
  environment:
    - HTTPS_METHOD=noredirect
```

1. **Restart**: After changes, run:

```
bash
docker-compose down
docker-compose up -d
```

1. **Test**:

```
bash
curl -H "Host: whoami.media.local" media.local
```

This should resolve the `301 Moved Permanently` issue.